# Vue – pass variable from child template to App.vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I read up on passing variables from child to parent using `$emit` but I can't fully figure it out yet.

In App.vue I have a `<header/>` component for the page header containing a button which controls the mobile navigation's visibility. On click it changes its class:

```
<button @click="toggleMobileNavigation" :class="isOpen ? 'is-open' : 'is-closed'">
```

The `<header/>`'s js:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleMobileNavigation() {
      if(!this.isOpen) {
        this.isOpen = true;
      } else {
        this.isOpen = false;
      }
      this.$emit(this.isOpen)
    }
  }
}
```

The App.vue:

```
<Header />
<main id="main" tabindex="-1" class="main" :class="isOpen">
```

This obviously this doesn't work and I can't figure out what the right way is to catch the `$emit`.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: use vuex, or make header a plugin which has its own event bus, or pass a global `:state="state"` prop around which has a header.isOpen prop, or add a ref to header and access through this.$refs.header, or a global event bus or traverse up from `this` to $root then into header component, there is a few ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you are on the right track, this child needs to emit some event to alert its parent of an important change.

But instead of doing this in your Header component:

```
      this.$emit(this.isOpen)
```

Supply an event name:

```
      this.$emit('opened', this.isOpen)
      // or:
      if (this.isOpen) { 
          this.$emit('opened');
      } else {
          this.$emit('closed');
      }
```

The way you catch this event in the parent component (App.vue) should be:

```
<Header @opened="handleOpenedEvent">  // will call method handleOpenedEvent
// alternatively:
<Header @opened="menuStatus = $event"> // $event contains data you supply as second argument to your this.$emit(name, ...) call

// @[eventname] is one way of doing it, v-on is the same:
<Header v-on:opened="handleEvent">
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks your answer, it brought me on the right track. Somehow I also have to set `emits: ["sendnavigationstatus"]` in `export default` inside the child template. Anyways, thx al lot Joshua and have a happy new year!

Comment: Hi Anna, I wasn't aware of that (emits property) being neccessary, I've tried to look for this in the Vue docs but couldn't find it. Could you point me in the right direction? Happy new year to you too.

Comment: I found it in the v3 docs https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/emits-option.html#_2-x-behavior and then it was kind of trial and error

Comment: Yeah all the child to parent tutorials don't mention it so I'm sure there's a more elegant solution. But I'm very new to Vue so I guess I'll go with this version instead of reading 100 tutorials : D

Comment: Thanks, learned something! I was working with Vue 2 that's why I missed it!

Comment: While I have you here, lol: do you maybe know how I would access the passed variable in a class name? My parent method is `navigationStatus(value) {let isOpen = value; console.log(isOpen)}` however I can't access `isOpen` in `:class="isOpen"`. I guess because it's not inside `data()`? (`isOpen` is a string 'is-open')

Comment: Like here https://michaelnthiessen.com/dynamically-add-class-name/

Comment: It says *Property "isOpen" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance* though.

Comment: You have this local variable (let isOpen), which is something Vue doesn't know exists. I would add isOpen to the data function, in navigationStatus() replace the local variable isOpen with this.isOpen. That should work, at least in Vue 2 i know it will ;-). If you use Vue3 composition api with those ref types maybe look here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html

Comment: Another thing to note about the dynamic class names, you use it this way: `:class='{someClass: isOpen}'` or `:class=" 'dynamic-string' + (isOpen ? 'opened' : '')"'`

Comment: Thanks Joshua, putting `this` before `isOpen` worked!